# PayPal API Subscription Shows 0 (zero) as the purchase total

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I'm using the PayPal API from PHP/Laravel and the purchase total is bugged. It results in a payment with the correct amount from the credit card, but when showing the amount to the customer during checkout, it only shows a 0 total

[checkout screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS8zv.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Do not include a start_time (date) when creating the subscription.

> https://prnt.sc/pOK5-7v5ZYMY

You should *always* uput text in code blocks, either with indentation or surrounded by three backticks, ``` before and after the code. Never take a screenshot of code.

It would appear you are using the old PayPal-PHP-SDK, which is deprecated. Do not use it for anything. (separately, that SDK also uses an older version of PayPal Subscriptions with billing agreements; current Subscriptions API does not use agreements).

The current version of PayPal Subscriptions integrations is [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/).  There is no REST SDK for it. For any API calls, you can use direct HTTPS REST calls, first obtaining an access_token using the client id and secret. The [standard integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) has sample code in node which you can use as a base.

Comment: When I remove it, the payment completely stops working. https://prnt.sc/pOK5-7v5ZYMY this is the code

Comment: Updated answer....

Comment: Thanks! just get confues why 0,00 EUR appears. Without starttime it works. Its because the start time was in the past. Amaaaaazing